Use available space under centered view
I've tried VStacks and Spacers.  GeometryReaders seem really overkill and I wasn't able to figure it out with AlignmentGuides.
I want to keep my blue square content dead center in the middle, and put a menu underneath in the remaining space.  Everything I do pushes the blue square up.  Whats the best way to achieve this layout?
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
  @StateObject private var gameState = GameState()
  
  var body: some View {
    // Blue Square
    VStack {
      Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  Test()
}



See How to make Image center of the screen and below it a label in swiftUI for various ways of doing it.

All those seem hacky and rely on hardcoded values.  Also his question asks for an offset of 50, I want to center in the remaining space.

@Ashbury At least in my answer there, the values aren't really "hardcoded". They are only hardcoded because the requirements in that question are hardcoded. The 70 in dimension[.top] + 70 for example, is half the height of the image. In your case, you can use dimension[.top] + (dimension[.trailing] - dimension[.leading]) / 2, where dimension[.trailing] - dimension[.leading] is the width (and also height) of the blue content. Please take some time to understand what the code there is doing, and apply it.

If you want something that doesn't "seem hacky", please objectively define what "hacky" means. Your question mentions alignmentGuide, and my answer there used alignmentGuide, what more do you ask for?

@Ashbury If you use a hidden placeholder then there are no hard-coded values (part 1 of my answer to the other post). It's a matter of opinion whether you think that approach is hacky, but it's a very common technique and perfectly valid, imho.

I didn't mean to diss your answer but coming from a webdev background this is a somewhat mind boggling way to achieve a layout.  Just not used to these methods!

@Sweeper your answer could be fine, in fact I'm trying it now.  I meant hacky in a sense that the dimension[.top] + 70 is hardcoded in that specific question.  You clarified that it could be modified but thats not obvious to someone new to swift who doesn't know whats possible.

I've just thought of a third approach, and I have edited that into my answer in the duplicate target.

Ok @Sweeper I can confirm it works for placing text without hardcoding it, like this:
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
      Text("Hello Swift")
        .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .semibold))
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .background(Color.green)
        .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { dimension in
          return dimension[.top] - (dimension[.trailing] + dimension[.leading]) / 2            }
    }

But I'd really like to figure out how to put a red box there that takes up the remaining space.

If you want to be able to fill the area, the alignmentGuide approach is less suitable. The third option I just added, or Benzy Neez's approach, is more suitable.

I have decided to reopen this as you have clarified that you want to fill the remaining space, and that you want the buttons to be centered with regards to the remaining space. This is subtly different from just adding views with a natural size after the blue content.

All you need to do is to find some view that naturally expands to fill space, and put them before and after the blue content. Adding these will not change the position of the blue content because the two "greedy" views will take up the same space.
Then, you can put your buttons as an overlay on the second "greedy" view.
Colors and Shapes are "greedy", so here I used Color.clear for the top of the blue content, and a stroked Rectangle as the bottom of the blue content.
VStack {
    Color.clear
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    Rectangle().stroke(.red, lineWidth: 10)
        .overlay {
            VStack {
                Button("Button 1") {}
                Button("Button 2") {}
            }
        }
}

Output:


Quick question, what is the cause of the small gap between the red and the blue?  More apparent when the red linewidth is 1.  Looks like about 10px on my screen.

@Ashbury That's the default spacing of the VStack. Use VStack(spacing: 0) if you don't want that.

Roger that, thank you!
